# Pass a C# struct with string to a C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, string, struct

I have a C# struct that I pass via UDP to a C++ application. I checked the length of a string field and got different results for the C# and C++ codes. Here are the definitions of the structs:

```
//  C# Side
//-------------
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct stName
{
 /// Some data types
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTstr, SizeConst = 20)]
 string StringName;
}

// C Side
//---------
struct stName{
/// Some data types
char StringName[20];
```

When StringName = "192.168.53.2" the size of that field at the C# side is 12 while it is 20 on the C side. What am I doing wrong? If C# uses the actual length of the string, what does the field SizeConst stand for?

Comment: you are passing a TString, you should use `LPStr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the length of the string in C#, it counts the number of characters (`192.168.53.2` is, correctly, 12 characters long).

However, in C, a string is really just an array of characters which is null-terminated. However, the size of the array in this case is just what you set it to, which is 20. So the size of this "field" is 20.

The `SizeConst` field refers to the size of the C array, so that the interop can create the C array appropriately (with the correct total size).